# Getting started with FuelUX and MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, fuelux

I would like to use DatePicker of FuelUX library. But looks like its not so easy to getting started with FuelUX. DatePicker.js is not a standalone file. It needs Require.js. And possibly some css files.
I want to bundle all static files. So I would like not to include cdn URLs to FuelUX files.
How are you guys bundling this library?
Although I am looking just for DatePicker, please do not hesitate to write if you had success with the whole library itself.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever use Fuel?  The data grid (Repeater) looks great and I am thinking of adding to my project.